# Referencing multiple points into same class

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I have a 3 interfaces that should be defined within a single class.

for instance

```
public class ChitChats : IServers, IClients, IInternalOnly 
{ 
   protected void SendChatMsg() { }
   public void SendMsg() { SendChatMsg(); }
}
```

The catch I have is each interface is actually a different executable that references the same framework assembly. All im trying todo is making sure that the relevant executable reference is not allwoed to see the other exposed available types.

My question is how would I be able to reference a single word / boject where it's underlying base type can swap based on other criteria.

For instance I would be able todo

```
IServers.SendMsg() // Works
IClients.SendMsg() // Breaks
IInternalOnly.SendMsg() // Works as it inherits from IServers ...
```

but I only want to use a single Interface name for everywhere else.
but it should be smart enough to know which interface to link for me ...

```
IAwesomeInterface.SendMsg(); // Works ... <g> .. we dont care what was implemented out of the available options.
```

Comment: Accept some answers?  Maybe?

Comment: `each interface is actually a different executable that references the same framework assembly` What kind of moon language is this? Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: i have about 80 projects that makes up the solution. The Core Framework has say 3 references to it. Server Porject, Client Project, and then internal to my company. The sections of code can be divided using #if blocks with compiler attributes. thou - very nice. i have almost a thousand interfaces to implement ...

Answer (score 2):

You need to choose a single common name - the ability to `SendMsg()` would be the job of an `IMessageSender` that way you only need to declare that idea once in your cognitive space.